# Skipping AMEB Music of Theory grades?

Tags: theory, exam-grades, exam

I understand that each grade teaches musical terminology, etc.that will be incorporated into the next grade, but I was wondering if skipping AMEB Music of Theory grades was possible or is there a required grade that I have to take? Or is there a limit to how many grades I can skip? If no, what grades do you recommend I can skip (provided that I just briefly study the needed knowledge but not take the exam)? Cheers ~

Answer (score 1):

Grades are often skipped, both practical and theory.

In ABRSM, not sure about AMEB, grade V theory must be passed to be able to enter grade VI and above practical.

The theory syllabus is usually cumulative - it keeps adding to the previous stuff - so just looking at, say, grade V, will not give you enough information to pass. You'll need to be aware of all the things in the previous syllabi. So yes, skip the *exams*, but not the study.